# Delphi / Amazon S3 exe not backward compatible

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, delphi, amazon-s3, compatibility

I am trying to create a simple directory watcher to monitor a directory and move new files meeting certain criteria to an Amazon S3 bucket.  It's purpose is to make files created by remote systems available immediately for publishing to a website.  We have many contributors using a range of Windows versions so compatibility is vital.  In concept this is probably the most advanced bit of coding I have so far attempted with Delphi.

Up to now I have never experienced any issues moving .exe files between Windows 10, Windows 7, Vista and XP.  I am using Delphi XE4 which will only allow me to build for Win32 platforms. My development PC is Windows 10.  I am building with Link Runtime Packages = False.

The exe detects and uploads files on Windows 10 PCs but will not run under XP / Vista / Windows 10.  It gives memory violation errors as soon as an S3 upload is initiated - or (on XP) it sits there doing nothing.

I thought it was something to do with the Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI, IPPeerCommon or IndyPeerImpl units because there is nothing else in my code that I haven't transported across windows versions successfully before.

I created a simpler version of the code (attached) to explore the problem.  Removing exception processing I get the message "The shared key cannot be created.  Please check you have the required OpenSSL Libraries" which occurs on TAmazonStorageService.Create.

I think I've reached the limit of my knowledge and experience with this one.  I can't see OpenSSL packages in the Delphi distribution.  How do I get this to run on XP / Vista / Windows 7? Am I missing some DLLs somewhere?

```
Unit Unit2;

interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI, Vcl.StdCtrls,System.IOUtils, IPPeerCommon, IndyPeerImpl  ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation


function UploadToS3(FileIn: TBytes; FileName: string; Bucket: string): boolean;
var Service: TAmazonStorageService ;
    ConAmazon: TAmazonConnectionInfo;
begin
  try
    ConAmazon := TAmazonConnectionInfo.Create(nil);
    ConAmazon.AccountKey    := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    ConAmazon.AccountName   := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    ConAmazon.QueueEndpoint     := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint   := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    ConAmazon.TableEndpoint     := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    ConAmazon.UseDefaultEndpoints := False;
    Service := TAmazonStorageService.Create(ConAmazon);
    Result := Service.UploadObject(Bucket, FileName, FileIn, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, nil);
  finally
    ConAmazon.Free;
    Service.Free;
  end;
end;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var b:TBytes;
begin

b := TFile.ReadAllBytes('C:\Users\wow\Documents\file.txt');
if UploadToS3(b, 'file.txt', 'bucket_name') then  showmessage('1') else  showmessage('0');
end;

end.
```

Comment: OpenSSL is a 3rd party open source library. You have to download it online and then deploy its 2 DLLs with your app.

Comment: Many thanks, I found these and its all working great.